# Unable to import ParamList in GPflow 2.9.0

Tags: gps, gpflow

I am trying to reimplement the following DNN mean function in GPflow 2.9.0:
https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.1-docs/notebooks/tailor/external-mean-function.html

However, I am unable to import ParamList or find it in the docs.
Is there any workaround possible?

Thanks in advance.

Searched through https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow
expected to be able to import ParamList as is done with Parameter

Comment: Short update.: And I not sure if that was the right fix (I am currently still testing and performing experiments) - but just removing ParamList works for the DNN mean function. ParamList seems to be not necessary, as each Ws and bs is defined as a Parameter.

Comment: Problem solved :) found the 2.9.0 version of this https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/2.9.0/notebooks/tailor/external-mean-function.html